Use 8-neighbor connectivity in eCognition segmentation
I'm working on image segmentation in eCognition 9.0 using images with abundant linear features (so at certain points they only connect diagonally). Is there a way to use 8-neighbor connectivity when merging or growing regions so I can connect objects that are diagonally adjacent?
